# Cant make toggle arrow working (Android Studio)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make work my drawertoggle in my fragment but i have only a simple arrow who does not move(the code was generated with the basic android studio template)

Fragment:

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";


    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";


    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;


    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }


        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);


            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                        getString(R.string.title_section4),
                        getString(R.string.title_section5),

                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);


        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name


        )

        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

I really don't know where is the problem please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

> ```
>     mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
>             getActivity(),
>             mDrawerLayout,//relpace this line with following 
>             R.string.app_name,
>             R.string.app_name
>     )
> ```

Change

> ```
>   mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
>             R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
>             R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
>             R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
>             )
> ```